# What is the difference between window.customElements.define() and document.registerElement()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component

I have been reading some tutorials about web components (native, no polymer). I have seen two ways to register components and I'm a bit confused what to use. For the second one I actually receive a typescript error in vscode: `[ts] Property 'registerElement' does not exist on type 'Document'. Did you mean 'createElement'?`

```
/**
 * App
 */
export class App extends HTMLElement {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = this.template;
    }

    get template() {
        return `
        <div>This is a div</div>
        `;
    }
}

// What is the difference between these two methods?
window.customElements.define('vs-app', App);
document.registerElement('vs-app', App);
```

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement), `registerElement` is deprecated, so don't use it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In terms of results, they accomplish pretty much the same. However, [`Document.registerElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement) is deprecated, so you should use [`CustomElementRegistry.define()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) instead.

In my eyes, the key difference is that `.registerElement()` returns a constructor for the new element, whereas `.define()` allows you to specify the constructor, allowing for greater versatility. Consider the folowing examples:

```
var MyElement = document.registerElement('me-me');
document.body.appendChild(new MyElement());
var myElement = document.getElementsByTagName('me-me')[0];
myElement.textContent = 'I am a custom element.';
```

---

```
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.textContent = 'I am a custom element.';
  }
}
customElements.define('me-me', MyElement);
document.body.appendChild(new MyElement());
```

As you can see, using `.define()` allows you to specify the inner text beforehand, whereas you have to manually specify the text in the case of `.registerElement()`. Provided this is a very simple example to showcase my point, using `.define()`, you can add a lot more to the default behavior, appearance and content of a custom element than you can with `.registerElement()`.

Comment: Wow, that was a really thorough explanation. Thanks!